# Equivalent to `stty size` on Windows

Tags: windows, terminal

I'm using some Ruby code that shells out to `stty size` to get the size of the terminal, but I'm running on Windows. What is the Windows equivalent?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The MODE command will report the size of the window buffer but not the actual window size.

You may have to write a utility to get the window size using GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo.

See: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/getconsolescreenbufferinfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683171(v=VS.85).aspx)